# How to convert pixel co-ordinates to world co-ordinates?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose, I have some points `(x_k, y_k)` in pixel space. I need to convert them to world co-ordinate. I have the homography matrix which is of `3 x 3` dimension. How to do it?

Comment: You need the camera parameters to do that (Extrinsic and Intrinsic).  Having just the homography is not enough.  A homography describes a mapping between one image to another, not image to the world.

Comment: @rayryeng Generally, a homography maps from one plane to another plane. So if it maps from the x-y-World-plane to the image plane (or the other way around), and it is known that the image points originated from points of that plane, it is possible to compute the corresponding world coordinates.

Comment: @chtz that's true and I stand corrected. However we don't know what that homography is so until I know that, the question can't be answered.

Comment: I agree, as it is, the question is unclear.

Comment: @chtz Yes. I have multiplied Pseudoinverse of homography matrix H with the world-coordinate to get the image plane. Now, if I can multiply this homography matrix H with the image plane, I should get world-plane. RIght? Sorry for the naive question. I am a newbie in 3-D  computer vision.